# [azureservicebus - How to set MessageId using JMS in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, spring-jms, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Message Id gets overridden when sending message to Azure service bus using Spring JMS. Because of this reason, duplicate detection is not working as expected. I have read JMS documentation where it's been said that JMSMessageId can't be set by producer, it is reserved by JMS for internal usage. Now Problem here is how can I set MessageID to detect duplicate message.

Any help on this please?? Sample code that I have tried is mentioned below.

```
    jmsTemplate.send(topicName, new MessageCreator() {
        
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
            message.setJMSMessageID("0111111-order");
            message.setJMSCorrelationID("0111111");             
            message.writeBytes(strJsonOrder.getBytes());
            return message;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried doing this using a `MessagePostProcessor`, but it's also not working for me.
`jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, event, message -> {
 message.setJMSMessageID("A generated Message ID");
 return message;
});` I also tried calling `message.setStringProperty("MessageId", "A generated Message ID");` without success.

Answer (score 0):

The Service Bus team is considering [this feature request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/30058).